# Whole word search in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I´m trying to find the string `0` in Gmail.

When I try searching for `0`, Gmail shows me emails with strings like `0.049` but I am not interested in them. I am interested in emails that contein a zero isolated or in other words... I am trying to find the string `" 0 "`. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused - I just tried to search for " 0 " and it did correctly filter out anything with a 0.0 (as far as I can tell). Did you confirm that your suggested search doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this in Gmail because it [doesn't support stem searching](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/07/how-gmail-filter-email-matching-works.html) nor symbol searching.

Gmail separates words on most symbols, meaning that your `0.049` is being split up into the words `0` and `049`. When you search for `0`, it finds a match in the first word.

The reason that `" 0 "` wouldn't work is that Gmail ignores whitespace, which means that it is the exact same thing as searching for `0`.

If Gmail did support stem searching and symbol searching, you could use something like `-0.*` to negate those terms you don't want to find. However, even then this wouldn't be accurate since an email containing the following `0 test 0.049`, would incorrectly not be matched due to the negation in the search query.

Here are several solutions I can think of:

- If there is a common word followed by the `0`, you can search for both of them (e.g. `"0 test"`).
- If there is a small amount of numbers that you don't want to match, you could exclude them using a search such as `0 -049 -050 -051`, however, keep in mind that this will still have the same problem that an email with the text `0 test 0.049` won't be matched.
- Similar to the above solution, you could negate a search term, so you could use `0 -"0 049" "0 050" "0 051"`, this still has the same limitation as the above one. The only additional advantage it has is that it will still match an email with `0 test 049`, which may reduce the amount of incorrectly unmatched emails.
- If possible, change the email to convert the numbers to a single word with a character such as `_` separating the numbers. So instead of `0.049`, your email would contain `0_049`, which should be treated as a single word. This way the search `0` will match correctly. Obviously doing something like this can be very easy (e.g. if you are generating the emails yourself) or very difficult (e.g. if you have no control over how the emails are sent).

Answer (score 1):

If you click on "search options" after typing 0 in the search box, then you can use:  Has the words 0 and : doesn't have 0.0
Or any other combination that you don't want to see. Plus you can limit search to one area, look for mail with/without attachments etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is one thing you can do, albeit it's quite cumbersome: Import the set of email messages that you want to search in Mozilla Thunderbird. Install the *ImportExportTools* add-on and use it to export the messages locally to a searchable text format. Now use a tool such as Notepad++ to search for `0` and check "Whole words".